# Jetpack Compose Updating state in ViewModel where state is collection

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a ViewModel and screen which creates a list pf questions and has input for answers

```
@HiltViewModel
class QuestionnaireViewModel @Inject constructor (
    private val _questionRepository: QuestionRepository
): ViewModel() {

    data class AnswerState(
        val question: String,
        var answer: String
    )

    val questions: List<Questions> = _questionRepository.getQuestions("pole1")
    val questionAnswers = questions.map { q -> AnswerState(q.qText, "") }

    private val _viewState = MutableStateFlow<List<AnswerState>>(questionAnswers)
    val viewState = _viewState.asStateFlow() 

    fun updateAnswer(question: String, answer: String) {
        val updatedAnswerState = _viewState.value.toMutableList()
        updatedAnswerState .filter { as -> as.question == question }.get(0).answer = answer
        _viewState.value = updatedAnswerState
    }
```

So then in my screen

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun QuestionnaireScreen() {

    val viewModel: QuestionnaireViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val state by viewModel.viewState.collectAsState()

    Column(modifier = Modifier) {
        
        Text(...Some elements)
   
        Questionnaire(
            state = state,
            onAnswerTextChange = viewModel::updateAnswer,
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Questionnaire(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: List<QuestionnaireViewModel.AnswerState>,
    onAnswerTextChange: (String) -> Unit = {},
) {
    Column (
        modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    ) {
        state.forEach { questionAnswer ->
            QuestionCard(
                answerState = questionAnswer,
                onAnswerTextChange = onAnswerTextChange
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun QuestionCard(
    answerState: QuestionnaireViewModel.AnswerState,
    onAnswerTextChange: (String) -> Unit = {}
) {
    Column (
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text (
            text = answerState.question
        )
        
        TextField(
            value = answerState.answer,
            onValueChange = onAnswerTextChange
        )
    }
}
```

So how do I supply two params from my textfield onValueChange, one being the question text to locate the correct piece of state in my update method and then the actual value to update the state value? Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just change your lambda to take 2 strings, like so?

```
@Composable
private fun Questionnaire(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  state: List<QuestionnaireViewModel.AnswerState>,
  onAnswerTextChange: (String, String) -> Unit = {},
) {
  Column (
    modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
  ) {
    state.forEach { questionAnswer ->
      QuestionCard(
        answerState = questionAnswer,
        onAnswerTextChange = { newAnswer -> 
          onAnswerTextChange.invoke(questionAnswer.question, newAnswer)
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, my function type needs to take account of the two params like .. onAnswerTextChange: (String, String) -> Unit = {question: String, answer: String -> }